# How to avoid duplicate dependencies in multiple module android application

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-module

I have 2 modules in my android app. Core module and one feature module. Currently I have 3 dependencies common for these 2 modules and I am adding it in both modules gradle file (Which leads to more app size and redundancy). How to share these dependencies with multiple modules in android.

**core module dependencies**

```
   dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    api 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
}
```

**feature module dependencies**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    //implementation project(':testmodule')
    api project(path:':coreModule',configuration: 'default')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
}
```

Used `api` in core module and used it in feature module using  `api project(path:':coreModule',configuration: 'default')`

Answer (score 7):

If you are writing

```
implementation 'com.xxx.android.x:1.2342'
```

which means that the current module requires this dependency to work. There by you need to declare it explicitly in both modules

*One in core*

*One in other module*

You can remove these kind of reduntant duplicate dependencies by using
`api` other than `implementation`
because `api` is used for sharing a dependency in one module with the others.
So replace `impementation` with `api` for the duplicated dependencies.

For Example: Library uses `androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2`
Then inside library `build.gradle` add

```
api 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
```

here by you don't need to define it again in app module.

Comment: Yes i did it. added all dependencies in a shared module using 'api' and used it in core module using  "api project(path:':shared',configuration: 'default')"  but couldn't resolve dependency in core

Comment: @VIJESH please post your gradle

Comment: exclude module: 'modulename' is for excluding particular lib in a module. Issue is I am not able to access this library (added using api) in other modules

Comment: @VIJESH check the updated answer. I got your query now.

Comment: Thanks, I was exactly looking at it.

Answer (score 2):

Android studio always warns about the duplicate dependencies and those duplicate dependencies create a time-consuming over head while building the release-apk file.

You can first identify the duplicate dependencies using the following command:

```
gradle -q dependencies yourProject:dependencies --configuration compile
```

The command result will show you human-readable tree hierarchy of all dependencies as mentioned below.

```
compile - Classpath for compiling the main sources.
...
+--- project :yourProject
|    +--- com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.6
|    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.5
|    |    \--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.2.4
|    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1
...
```

Once you have identified the duplicate dependencies, you can exclude them from the specified library using the following syntax in your `build.gradle` file.

```
//OneSignal
api ('com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.6.2, 3.99.99]') {
    exclude group: 'android.arch.lifecycle', module: 'extensions'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
}
```

I hope this helps.